# functional equation, find $h$ continous on $\mathbf{R}$ such that $h(x) + h(2x) + h(4x) = {x^n}$

Tags: continuity, induction, functional-equations

I am having trouble finding easily $h$ defined and continuous on $\mathbf{R}$
verifying for all $x$ in $\mathbf{R}$,
 $$ h(x) + h(2x) + h(4x) = {x^n} $$
where $n$ is a fixed natural number.

I have a solution using induction, but it is far too long in my opinion.
Can anyone help me finding a simple solution ? 
Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle h(x) = \frac{(2^n-1)x^n}{8^n-1}.$  It is easy to check that this function satisfies the given functional equation.

Now suppose that we have two solutions $h_1(x)$ and $h_2(x)$ to the given equation (for a fixed $n$).  Consider the function $g(x) = h_1(x) - h_2(x)$.  We have that $g$ is continuous and that $g(x) + g(2x) + g(4x) = 0$ for all $x$.  In particular, this implies that $g(0) = 0$.  Also, $g(x/2) + g(x) + g(2x) = 0$ by substituting $x/2$ for $x$.  Hence $g(4x) = g(x/2)$ for all $x$; equivalently, $g(x) = g(x/8)$ for all $x$.

So for all $x$ we have, for all $k$, $g(x) = g(x/8^k)$, and hence $$g(x) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} g(x/8^k) = \lim_{z\rightarrow 0} g(z) = g(0) = 0.$$

This means that any two solutions to the functional equation are equal everywhere; that is, that the $h(x)$ given above is the only solution.

Comment: But how would you have found that $h$?

Comment: If you guess that $h(x) = cx^n$ you can solve for $c$ pretty easily.